# Multi-team microservices architecture

Tags: architecture, microservices

We have a trading applications which has different modules in it and each module has its set of tables which share single database. Each module also has its own services.

One team often requires data from other modules in show their UI/Reports and business logic. Currently the way we share the data is in the form of database views. So if I need data from other module, then they create views and provide it to us with all required data. We join to those views and use it accordingly.

I know this is not the scalable solutions. What other solutions are possible in this situation where performance/code reuse is critical.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider having CQRS pattern implemented by holding read only copies of the data along with the services.